# How to deal whith VHDL generics in code coverage

Tags: testing, vhdl, code-coverage

When testing a digital architecture written in **VHDL** and aiming for 100% code **coverage**, I don't really know how to deal with **generic** inputs.

In my case, I have a single component with *generic-dependant behaviour* that is instantiated twice. The instance have different ('0' and '1') values for this generic, which is meant to be and cannot be otherwise. 
Because of this, my code coverage cannot be 100 % (the generic value will always be '1' for one instance and '0' for the other).

I know I could decide to exclude verifications from the coverage but I'm not sure this is the best way to do. What is considered best practise in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The code coverage tool is probably (and should be) able to combine coverage from multiple simulation runs.

So you make 2 separate simulation runs with generic as '0' and '1' respectively, combine the coverage of these, and the combined coverage should then be 100%.

Comment: I agree with that but the problem is that this generic is not meant to take both values for each instance so making two separate simulations would not make much sense in that case. Plus I'm not a fan of doubling the simulation time if that can be avoided. (Sorry for the late reaction)

Comment: OK, so what you would like to do one simulation with 2 instances having respectively 0 and 1 as generic value.  The you should tell the coverage too to combine the coverage for the 2 instances, so anything covered in one instance will also count as coverage in the other and vise-versa.  Thereby you should be able to do with one simulation.